# ExoPlayer 2.11.1 DefaultBandwidthMeter(); deprecated

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, video-player

I am playing video on Android using ExoPlayer. But " DefaultBandwidthMeter();" is deprecated.

```
    DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

        //DefaultTrackSelector chooses tracks in the media item
        DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(this);
        trackSelector.setParameters(trackSelector.buildUponParameters().setMaxVideoSizeSd());
        mPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).setTrackSelector(trackSelector).build();

        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "exoplayerapp"), bandwidthMeter);
        MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url));

        mPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);

        playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        playerView.requestFocus();
        playerView.setPlayer(mPlayer);
        mPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        playBackStateListener = new PlayBackStateListener();
        mPlayer.addListener(playBackStateListener);
```

What should I use insead of this and according to that with what I should replace the following line which is using theis bandwidthMeter?

```
  DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "exoplayerapp"), bandwidthMeter);
```

Comment: ExoPlayer is still popular for deprecating it's methods faster. I used it in 2015-16

Answer (score 2):

You should use [DefaultBandwidthMeter.Builder](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/DefaultBandwidthMeter.Builder.html). Source from ExoPlayer [documentation](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/DefaultBandwidthMeter.html#%3Cinit%3E()).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `HLS` Media Type you should this:

```
val defaultHttpDataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
```

Note: It worked this version:  `implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.2'`